# How can I identify a double AES encrypted cipherText

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I mistakenly encrypted some of my values in the db twice.
Is there a way to identify double encrypted ciphertext.

```
    var ciphertext = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secretKey).toString();
    var ciphertext2 = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(ciphertext, secretKey).toString();
```

Comment: No apart from trying to decrypt and seeing what comes out.

Comment: As encryption is working on bytes (input and output) there is no chance to detect if a byte array is encrypted or not - but with the help of a "protocol" you can do: e.g. add a header like "enc:" to the ciphertext. At the start of the encrypt function to check for that header to avoid a double encryption (dirty but working :-).

Comment: @MichaelFehr `encrypt` without specifying a precise key uses an OpenSSL proprietary format, see my answer.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: you are right, I was talking about encryption in general. OpenSSL's encrypt is using some other kind of protocol with adding the "SALTED_" header.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, and both are high certainty but have drawbacks.

First of all, if you don't give an well formatted key / IV then CryptoJS will use an OpenSSL key derivation mechanism to derive the key and IV. If you use `toString()` it will then stringify the result. This of course adds some overhead, so if you know the original size of the message then you can simply try and detect double encryption by the increase of the size.

Second, you  can decrypt once, and then look for the format that `toString` generates. This is a base 64 string which, after decoding, should contain `Salted__` in ASCII (followed by the salt and then the AES-CBC / PKCS#7 ciphertext). As your plaintext is unlikely to start with `Salted__` this should be enough of a distinguisher. So your decrypt routine could run in a loop until the `Salted__` string isn't found anymore.

Otherwise: AES encrypted ciphertext is fully randomized, so you cannot see anything looking at the ciphertext itself. In this case however, the ciphertext is *part of* a proprietary protocol, which opens up some possiblities.